# Use Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> in Linq on MyEntity.<OtherEntity>.<MyProperty>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to simplify a method that returns an IQueryable

A, B and C extend BaseEntity containing a enum that I want to compare.
context is a entity framework dbcontext.

Here is a stripped down version of the method:

```
 return context.MyEntities.Include("A").Include("B").Include("C")
        .Where(x => x.A.MyEnum == MyEnum.<value> && x.B.MyEnum == MyEnum.<value> && x.C.MyEnum == MyEnum.<value>);
```

I tried to do this:

```
Func<BaseEntity, bool> equals = x => x.MyEnum == MyEnum.<value>;

return context.MyEntities.Include("A").Include("B").Include("C")
        .Where(x => equals(x.A) && equals(x.B) && equals(x.C));
```

It compiles but gives a runtime error. For what I understand is that Linq cannot translate the func<> to SQL?
So i searched and I found that you need to wrap the func<> in an expression<>, so Linq can compile it and translate it to SQL.

Now I have this:

```
Expression<Func<BaseEntity, bool>> equals = x => x.MyEnum == MyEnum.<value>;

return context.MyEntities.Include("A").Include("B").Include("C")
        .Where(x => equals(x.A) && equals(x.B) && equals(x.C));
```

But this doesn't compile: 'Method name expected'.
Is there a way to accomplish what i'm trying to do?

Comment: My eyes can't compiles this `x => x.A.<MyProperty> == 1`. Are you sure about your starting point ?

Comment: Maybe I over simplified. I updated my question with enums, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Use a predicate builder. For instance [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of of your problem.

Comment: @NKosi can you elaborate?

Comment: @Bensjero https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error is because you have to first compile the expression before being able to invoke it.

```
equals.Compile()(x.A)
```

But this defeats the purpose of using the expression to begin with.

There is nothing to be simplified in the provided code other than moving the repeated value call into a variable.

```
var value = MyEnum.<value>;
return context.MyEntities.Include("A").Include("B").Include("C")
    .Where(x => x.A.MyEnum == value && x.B.MyEnum == value && x.C.MyEnum == value);
```

The attempt to simplify what was shown is not really needed.

Comment: I agree, with the given code in mind. But, for learning purposes, is my idea possible?